# Visio Textboxes - Tab/Enter to Advance

Tags: vba, winforms, visio, designmode, shapesheet

I'm trying to a create few textboxes grouped within a Mastershape that will tab to the next textbox in sequence, or exit the sequence if you press enter.

I would like to do this with the shapesheet for the Mastershape, but I think it will be more complicated than that.

I'm thinking I may have to use TheText event in shapesheet to call a function, sort through the user keystroke, and then move selection to the next textbox if necessary.

Would it be easier to use the WinForm textboxes instead? I've tried this, but the mastershape template has trouble grouping and keeping everything together

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have a commercial VBA software I write and we use the TheText event like you said.  We look for a CR or TAB char, and if we find that we pick the next shape, select it, and call Application.DoCmd(visCmdTextEditState)

Comment: Great to know! How do you find the next shape? So far I think that I should grab the master name and find the next shape in that Master, but I'm unclear how to do that in code

Comment: Our code uses proximity, so we use the Shape.SpatialNeighbors method for finding the shape touching  the current shape.  To find the next shape of that master you could index through the shapes on the page starting at the current shape's index + 1, and stop when you find another shape with the same master.

Comment: If I know the Master name and the Textbox name that I want to select next, how can I shift focus to that shape in code? I'm having a hard time figuring that out

Comment: You just have to do Application.ActiveWindow.DeselectAll, then Application.ActiveWindow.Select ShpObj, visSelect.  Where ShpObj is the shape you want to shift focus to

Comment: Alright, I've finally gotten it to select the next box. (I had to use visSubSelect). I'm still having trouble getting the text window to open automatically for editing. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when the Application.DoCmd(visCmdTextEditState) line runs?

Comment: Oh, I'm terribly sorry, I was so focused on getting the other stuff to start working that I forgot you answered my question previously. Thank you very much, DoCmd works perfectly.